# Can we create and use Temporary tables in DataStage?

Tags: odbc, temp-tables, datastage

Is it possible to create and/or use temporary tables in the ODBC connector stage of the DataStage?

I'm trying to update the data using a #Temp table in the join statement immediately after populating the Temp table.
I had looked according to the error form the job's log file but couldn't understand what it says, 
Error message:

```
Unrecognized argument: variant='3.5\', 
   library=ccodbc, 
   version=1.0, 
   variantlist=\'V1;3.5::ccodbc\', 
   versionlist=\'1.0\', 
   name=ODBCConnector
}'

 SAX parser exception thrown: The input ended before all started tags were ended. Last tag started was 'before' (CC_PropertySet::fatalError, file CC_PropertySet.cpp, line 2,266)
```

Comment: Please specify the database system you are using

Comment: Microsoft SQL Server 2014

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got a solution!

Yes, we can use #Temp tables of SQL Server in DataStage ODBC stage, the query was absolutely perfect but the thing is DataStage couldn't prase the SQL Query. It considered it as DataStage parameter (since parameters in DataStage were bounded with #ParameterName#) So the DataStage compiler consider it as a incomplete parameter and thrown the error as above.

Solution: Use **[** #Temp_Table **]** to solve the issue.